# find the duplicate word from a sentence with count using for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, count, duplicates

As i am new to java i got a task to find duplicate word only and its count. i stuck in a place and i am unable to get the appropriate output. I can not use any collections and built in tool. i tried the below code. Need some help, Please help me out.

```
public class RepeatedWord 
  {
   public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          String sen = "hi hello hi good morning hello";
          String word[] = sen.split(" ");
          int count=0;
          for( int i=0;i<word.length;i++)
             {
                for( int j=0;j<word.length;j++)
                   {
                       if(word[i].equals(word[j]))
                          {
                             count++;
                          }
                         if(count>1)
                   System.out.println("the word "+word[i]+" occured"+ count+" time");
                   }

             }

       }
 }
```

expecting output:-

```
the word hi occured 2 time
the word hello occured 2 time
```

but i am getting output like below :-

```
the word hi occured 2 time
the word hi occured 2 time
the word hi occured 2 time
the word hi occured 2 time
the word hello occured 2 time
the word hi occured 2 time
the word hi occured 2 time
the word hi occured 2 time
the word hi occured 2 time
the word hello occured 2 time
```

please help me to get the output like i am expecting. and please explain. so that i can understand too.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: are you allowed to use Map?

Comment: @redflar3 no. have to use for loop only.

Comment: you cannot give print inside any of these loops as we have no way to find which is the last match for a given word. Due to the same, we have to have some mechanism to store the occurrences in some form. An idea way is to create a Map and whenever you find a match, you store the value in map with key as word and value as 1, if word already in Map, you can increment the value.

Comment: also, the output mentioned in OP is not the real output as you are using just one `count` variable, which will keep incrementing irrespective of word.

Comment: @redflar3 for this code i am getting output like above not like expectation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to print the result only for the outer loop. Also, you need to avoid checking the words that were already checked in previous iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    int count = 0; // reset the counter for each word

    for (int j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {

        if (word[i].equals(word[j])) {
            /* if the words are the same, but j < i, it was already calculated
               and printed earlier, so we can stop checking the current word
               and move on to another one */
            if (j < i) {
                break; // exit the inner loop, continue with the outer one
            }

            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count > 1) {
        System.out.println("the word " + word[i] + " occured " + count + " time");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Additional explanation around this code: `if (j < i) { break; }`

`i` is the index of the word we calculate duplicates for, `j` is the word we compare it against. Since we start always from beginning, we know that if the words are equal while `j < i`, it was already processed in earlier run of the outer loop.

In this case, using `break`, we interrupt the inner loop and the flow continues in the outer loop. As we didn't update `count` at all, it is still zero and thus the condition for printing the result `if (count > 1)` is not satisfied and the `println` is not executed.

Example for the word "hello", using simple pseudo-code in the following part.

For its first occurrence:

```
count = 0
    i = 1, j = 0 --> hello != hi                  --> do nothing
    i = 1, j = 1 --> hello == hello, j is not < i --> count++
    i = 1, j = 2 --> hello != hi                  --> do nothing
    i = 1, j = 3 --> hello != good                --> do nothing
    i = 1, j = 4 --> hello != morning             --> do nothing
    i = 1, j = 5 --> hello == hello, j is not < i --> count++
count > 1        --> print the result
```

For its second occurrence:

```
count = 0
    i = 5, j = 0 --> hello != hi           --> do nothing
    i = 5, j = 1 --> hello == hello, j < i --> break, we have seen this pair earlier
count is not > 1 --> result not printed
```

Hope I didn't make things more complicated with this example

Comment: @Sva.Mu can you say `if (j < i) 
          {
                break;
            }`

what happening here

Comment: Tried to explain in the code comments, but give me a few minutes and I will update the answer with more details.

Comment: that is to ensure an already printed word is not counted again. why dont you remove the lines and see what happens... put some additional print statements to see the execution \flow..

Comment: Added some more detailed explanation to the answer, hope it clarifies a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

**Print Outside first for loop,This will do the trick and initialize count=0 in for loop beginning**

```
 for( int i=0;i<word.length;i++)
             {
                count=0;
                for( int j=0;j<word.length;j++)
                   {
                       if(word[i].equals(word[j]))
                          {
                             count++;
                          }
                   }
     if(count>1)
     System.out.println("the word "+word[i]+" occured"+ count+" time");
             }
```

Comment: still i am getting multiple output as it is coming inside first for loop.

Comment: check ithe condition outside

Comment: after doing this i am getting out put like
` the word hi occured 2 time
the word hello occured 2 time
the word hi occured 2 time
the word hello occured 2 time`

i need only

`the word hi occured 2 time
the word hello occured 2 time`

Comment: check ive edited,this will defnitley work,i tried,sorry for inconvience tho

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
import java.util.*; 
class test{
public static void main(String[] args){
String s;
int count=0;
int count1=0;

System.out.println("Enter the Sentence");
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
s=scan.nextLine(); 
System.out.println(s);
String[] arr=s.split(" ");

String[] srr=new String[arr.length];
int[] rev=new int[arr.length];
 for(int i=0;i<arr.length; i++)
   { if(arr[i]!="NULL"){
   String temp=arr[i];

 for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length; j++)
 {
 if(temp.equals(arr[j]))
 {
   arr[j]="NULL";
 count++;

 }

   }

  srr[count1]=temp;
 rev[count1]=count;
 count=0;
 count1++;
  }

  }
 for(int i=0;i<count1;i++)
  System.out.println(srr[i]+"  "+rev[i]);
  }
  }
```