# how to count duplicate substring from given String in java

Tags: java, for-loop, collections

In this example i m not able to count "manoj" in the given string...how i can 
  do this..

```
String text = "manoj kumjjjartiwarimanojmanoj";
char[] line = text.toCharArray();
char[] temp = "manoj".toCharArray();
int count=0;

for (int i =0; i < line.length; i++) {  
    int t =0;
    for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
        if(line[i]==temp[j]){
            t=1;
        }
        else{
            t=0;
        }
    }
    if(t==1){
        count=count+1;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find the duplicate word from a sentence with count using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798271/find-the-duplicate-word-from-a-sentence-with-count-using-for-loop)

Comment: There is no need to use any loop for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with various method , you should really search this on google before asking, but i am providing a code

```
String text = "manoj kumjjjartiwarimanojmanoj";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("manoj");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
int count = 0;
while (m.find())
{
   count +=1;
}
```

Comment: A simple for loop starting at each character would be much cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `substring` and `startsWith` of the `String` class directly:

```
String text = "manoj kumjjjartiwarimanojmanoj";
String search = "manoj";

int count = 0;
for (int i=0; i < text.length() - search.length(); i++) {
    if (text.substring(i).startsWith(search)) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Prints 2

This will also count all occurrences in cases like searching for "aa" in "aaaaaa" (resulting in 5).

Answer (score 0):

```
String pattern="manoj"
String text = "manoj kumjjjartiwarimanojmanoj";
String text2 = text.replaceAll (pattern, "") 
(text.length() - text2.length())/pattern.length ()
```

Result: 3, is it correct?

Note, that a resulting *manoj*, like in input "mamanojnoj" will not be replaced by replaceAll, which might be in your interest.